# use of undeclared crate or module `sp_runtime`

Tags: pallet

i need to create nft pallet with substrate . i have write these codes but when i run this command : `cargo build --release` it show me this errors :

```
  --- stderr
     Compiling base-nft v4.0.0-dev (/home/kianoush/blockchain_project/substrate_nft/pallets/base-nft)
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `sp_runtime`
    --> /home/kianoush/blockchain_project/substrate_nft/pallets/base-nft/src/lib.rs:14:5
     |
  14 | use sp_runtime::{
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `sp_runtime`

  error[E0432]: unresolved import `sp_runtime`
    --> /home/kianoush/blockchain_project/substrate_nft/pallets/base-nft/src/lib.rs:14:5
     |
  14 | use sp_runtime::{
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `frame_support::sp_runtime`
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this error ?**

My Codes :

```
    #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#[warn(unused_imports)]

use frame_support::{
    inherent::Vec,
    pallet_prelude::{ValueQuery, *},
    traits::Currency,Twox64Concat,
};
use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
/// Edit this file to define custom logic or remove it if it is not needed.
/// Learn more about FRAME and the core library of Substrate FRAME pallets:
/// <https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/frame>
pub use pallet::*;
use sp_runtime::{
    traits::{
        AtLeast32BitUnsigned, CheckedAdd, CheckedSub, Hash, MaybeSerializeDeserialize, Member, One,
        Zero,
    },
    DispatchError, DispatchResult,
};

/// Class info
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(TokenId, AccountId, Data))]
pub struct ClassInfo<TokenId, AccountId, Data> {
    /// Class metadata
    pub metadata: Vec<u8>,
    /// Total issuance for the class
    pub total_issuance: TokenId,
    /// Class owner
    pub owner: AccountId,
    /// Class Properties
    pub data: Data,
}

#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(AccountId, Data))]
pub struct TokenInfo<AccountId, Data> {
    /// Token metadata
    pub metadata: Vec<u8>,
    /// Token owner
    pub owners: Vec<AccountId>,
    /// Token Properties
    pub data: Data,
}

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {

    use super::*;

    #[derive(Default, Encode, Decode, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug)]
    pub struct TokenByOwnerData {
        pub percent_owned: u8,
        pub token_id: u32,
    }

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
        /// The class ID type
        type ClassId: Parameter + Member + Default + Copy;
        /// The token ID type
        type TokenId: Parameter + Member + Default + Copy;
        /// The class properties type
        type ClassData: Parameter + Member + Default;
        /// The token properties type
        type TokenData: Parameter + Member + Default;
    }

    pub type ClassInfoOf<T> = ClassInfo<
        <T as Config>::TokenId,
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        <T as Config>::ClassData,
    >;
    pub type TokenInfoOf<T> =
        TokenInfo<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as Config>::TokenData>;

    pub type GenesisTokenData<T> = (
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, // Token owner
        Vec<u8>,                                // Token metadata
        <T as Config>::TokenData,
    );
    pub type GenesisTokens<T> = (
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, // Token class owner
        Vec<u8>,                                // Token class metadata
        <T as Config>::ClassData,
        Vec<GenesisTokenData<T>>, // Vector of tokens belonging to this class
    );

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    #[pallet::without_storage_info]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    /// Next available class ID.
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn next_class_id)]
    pub type NextClassId<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, T::ClassId, ValueQuery>;

    /// Next available token ID.
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn next_token_id)]
    pub type NextTokenId<T: Config> =
        StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::ClassId, T::TokenId, ValueQuery>;

    /// Store class info.
    ///
    /// Returns `None` if class info not set or removed.
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn classes)]
    pub type Classes<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::ClassId, ClassInfoOf<T>>;

    /// Store token info.
    ///
    /// Returns `None` if token info not set or removed.
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn tokens)]
    pub type Tokens<T: Config> =
        StorageDoubleMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::ClassId, Twox64Concat, T::TokenId, TokenInfoOf<T>>;

    // Pallets use events to inform users when important changes are made.
    // https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/events-and-errors
    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        /// Event documentation should end with an array that provides descriptive names for event
        /// parameters. [something, who]
        SomethingStored(u32, T::AccountId),
    }

    /// Error for non-fungible-token module.
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// No available class ID
        NoAvailableClassId,
        /// No available token ID
        NoAvailableTokenId,
        /// Token(ClassId, TokenId) not found
        TokenNotFound,
        /// Class not found
        ClassNotFound,
        /// The operator is not the owner of the token and has no permission
        NoPermission,
        /// Arithmetic calculation overflow
        NumOverflow,
        /// Can not destroy class
        /// Total issuance is not 0
        CannotDestroyClass,
        /// Sender tried to send more ownership than they have
        SenderInsufficientPercentage,
        /// Wrong arguments
        WrongArguments,
    }

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {}
}

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn create_class(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        metadata: Vec<u8>,
        data: T::ClassData,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

        let class_id = NextClassId::<T>::try_mutate(|id| -> Result<T::ClassId, DispatchError> {
            let current_id = *id;
            *id = id.checked_add(&One::one()).ok_or(Error::<T>::NoAvailableClassId)?;
            Ok(current_id)
        })?;

        let info =
            ClassInfo { metadata, total_issuance: Default::default(), owner: who.clone(), data };
        Classes::<T>::insert(class_id, info);

        Ok(class_id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `sp-runtime` to your pallet's `Cargo.toml` file:

```
...
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "master" }
...
```

Or try to do what the compiler is telling you `"help: a similar path exists: frame_support::sp_runtime"`

```
use frame_support::sp_runtime::{<Module1>, <Module2>, ...},
```

Comment: And dont forget to add the crate to std features